# Stream raw sql query data in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, stream, sails.js, node-modules

Need help to stream sql data in sailsjs application, i could find that we can use stream directly on Sailsjs model but my query is bit complex and couldn't find anything to directly stream data from query to client.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Postgresql sample from sailsjs documentation.

```js
Pet.query('SELECT pet.name FROM pet WHERE pet.name = $1', [ 'dog' ] ,function(err, rawResult) {
  if (err) { return res.serverError(err); }

  sails.log(rawResult);
  // (result format depends on the SQL query that was passed in, and the adapter you're using)

  // Then parse the raw result and do whatever you like with it.

  return res.ok();
});
```

For further reference https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query